# Show only 2nd level of navigation depending on active navigation

Tags: menus, templates, navigation, sub-menu

For example, suppose a menu like so:

```
Parent 1
  Child A
  Child B
Parent 1
  Child C
  Child D
  Child E
Parent 2
  Child F
```

In a certain part of my template, I want something to show depending on the current "location" in the menu. If the user is on the `Parent 1`, `Child C`, `Child D`, or `Child E` pages, then I want a little menu to show up that says `Parent 1` as the header and the children as the links. I've tried a variety of things (creating a custom walker object, writing css to just not show the items that shouldn't show, etc.) Also, if there are no children at all, then I don't want to display the parent even on the parent's own page. Does this make sense?

I don't want a plugin that does/helps with this (I don't like to have my template "depend" on a plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - I've not implemented it fully, but I have tested it and it seems to work. Place it in your functions.php and call `<?php list_child_pages(); ?>` in your template or use the shortcode `[childpages]` in your editor.

```
<?php
// List Child pages of a parent. 
function list_child_pages() {

global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) { ?>
    <menu>
        <ul class="side-nav">
            <?php echo $string = $childpages; ?>
        </ul>
    </menu>
<?php   
}

return $string;

}
// Add Shortcode for additional support, not just in the theme template
add_shortcode('childpages', 'list_child_pages');

?>
```